# How would you design JSON Schema for an arbitrary key?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have the following JSON output data:

```
{
   "label_name_0" : 0,
   "label_name_5" : 3,
   .
   .
   .
   "label_name_XXX" : 4
}
```

The output is simple: a key[1] name associated with integer value. If the key name doesn't change, I can easily come up with JSON Schema similar to this:

```
    {
        "type": "array"
        "title": "Data output",
        "items" :{ 
            "properties": {
                "label_name": {
                   "type": "integer",
                   "default": 0,
                   "readonly": True,
            }
        }
    },
```

Since the key name itself is not known and keep changing, I have to design schema for it. The only thing I know is that the key is `string` and not more than 100 characters.  How do I define a JSON Schema for the key `lable_name_xxx` that keeps changing.

[1] Not sure if I am using the right terminology

Comment: You should accept @Konrad 's answer.

Comment: No, you should accept @mrtnlrsn's answer, it answers the problem with a simpler solution.

Answer (score 61):

On json-schema.org you will find something appropriate in the [File System Example](http://json-schema.org/learn/file-system.html#fstab-schema) section. You can define `patternProperties` inside an `object`.

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "/": {}
    },
    "patternProperties": {
        "^(label_name_[0-9]+)+$": { "type": "integer" }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false,
 }
```

The regular expression `(label_name_[0-9]+)+` should fit your needs. In JSON Schema regular expressions are explicitly anchored with `^` and `$`. The regular expressions defines, that there has to be at least one property (`+`). The property consists of `label_name_` and a number between `0` and `9` whereas there has to be at least one number `([0-9]+)`, but there can also arbitrary many of them.

By setting `additionalProperties` to `false` it constrains object properties to match the regular expression.

Comment: dead link. Documentation is at https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#pattern-properties

Comment: See @mrtnlrsn answer for a simpler solution that doesn't restrict the pattern of the key with a regular expression (if that isn't desired).

Answer (score 27):

As Konrad's answer stated, use `patternProperties`. But use in place of `properties`, which is not needed, and I think Konrad just pasted from his reference example that was expecting a path starting with `/`. In the example below, the pattern match `regex .*` accepts any property name and I am allowing types of string or null only by using `"additionalProperties": false`.

```
  "patternProperties": {
    "^.*$": {
      "anyOf": [
        {"type": "string"},
        {"type": "null"}
      ]
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
```

Comment: `additionalProperties` is useless for type constraint, it's declared by `anyOf`.

Comment: Pattern should be `^.+$` if the property name must not be empty. Then, the `"additionalProperties": false` must be set, too.

Answer (score 15):

Simpler solution than patternProperties, since OP does not have any requirement on the key names ([documentation](http://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#additional-properties)):

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": {
        "type": "integer",
        "default": 0,
        "readonly": true,
    }        
}
```

`default` and `readonly` included because they were included in the OP's initial suggestion, but they are not required.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for when searching for the same question as OP. Yours is the simplest solution, since no regular expression or limitation for key names is required.
This should be the accepted answer.